# Can't close flagging dialog and answer textarea overlaps it on iOS Safari

Tags: bug, ios, mobile-safari

I tried to flag a question on Stack Overflow and when the dialog prompted I wasn't able to close it nor scroll through the flagging options.

Update:
Went to another question to try again and it let me close the dialog but answer textarea continues to overlap it as shown in the picture.

Info:

- iPhone 5 with iOS 7
- Safari

Steps to reproduce:

- Click on flag
- Click on 'It should be closed fir another reason'
- Answer textarea overlaps and doesn't leave clicking in any other option that gets behind it.

Photo:

[image: Picture of collision between text and flag modal]
[Picture of collision between text and flag mod-l in private browsing http://es.tinypic.com/r/4uuyjo/8](http://es.tinypic.com/r/4uuyjo/8)

Comment: Maybe you should wait until you get home to post a question...

Comment: Can you clarify if you are using the mobile or full version of the site?

Comment: @Oded it's the mobile one.

Comment: @Zane yes, you're right. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot duplicate this bug.  I tried using Mobile Safari on iOS 6 and iOS 7 devices, using both the desktop site and the mobile site.  In all cases, I was able to scroll through, and close, the flagging modal.

Comment: added more info on the report. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks - I'm still unable to reproduce following your steps.

Comment: Anyting more I can do to help reproducing it out?

Comment: Does it persist if you use Private Browsing mode?  Also, maybe the layout of the flagging dialog is different based on rep.  If so, I may be getting served different HTML than you.

Comment: I've got < 1k rep so flagging options should ve normal ones. I'll try with private mode, when I took the screenshot I was using normal navigation.

Comment: it happens again on private browsing.